# Is there any way to include a <%= %> within another <%= %> without causing error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing a ruby application and in my .html.erb file I'm trying to create a form `<%=f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>` with a placeholder that displays current user's name (retrieved from `<%= current_user.name %>`)
However,I always encounter syntax error when I put <%= %> within another <%= %>. Is there anyway to allow putting <%= %> inside <%= %>?

Comment: you can simply used `<%=f.text_field :name, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "#{current_user.name}" %>`

Comment: @VishalJAIN: don't even need interpolation here.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do that. You just simply use something like this :

```
<%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: current_user.name %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
<%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "#{current_user.name}" %>
```

or

```
<%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: current_user.name %>
```

You don't need to add `<%= %>` inside of `<%= %>`.

Answer (score 0):

To give you some context (`@Chris V` is correct), `<%= %>` is known as ERB ([`Embedded Ruby`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ERuby) code):

> `eRuby (Embedded Ruby)` is a templating system that embeds Ruby into a text document. It is often used to embed Ruby code in an HTML document, similar to ASP, JSP and PHP.

--

Much like `<? echo "Something" %>` in PHP, `ERB` code parses everything inside the brackets as *ruby* code -- meaning if you're at a point where you could put `<%= %>` inside another set of brackets, the short answer is you don't need them.

You can simply keep it all in the same set of brackets: `<%= f.text_field :name, class: "class", placeholder: current_user.name %>`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use embedded ruby within embedded ruby.

You are probably trying to use this, which is causing the error:

```
<%=f.text_field :name, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => <%= current_user.name %> %>
```

It can be solved like this

```
<%=f.text_field :name, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => current_user.name %>
```